# Discord.JS Sharding Guild ID list problem

Tags: arrays, json, discord, discord.js

Im using Discord.JS Sharding and im trying to get all the guilds in from the 2 shards.

```
shard.broadcastEval("this.guilds.map(u => u.id).join('\\n')").then(result => {

 console.log(result)
})
```

Note: Nodejs is not taking \n so it wants `\\n` to even work... and i think thats where my error is but idk how to fix

it gives me this

```
["389019673557073925","469387242767646730\n537085738509008896"]
```

i want it to give me this

```
["389019673557073925","469387242767646730", "537085738509008896"]
```

i tried forEach and many other ways... If you can help me that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it will give you an array of guild ids per shard

```
    shard.broadcastEval("this.guilds.map(u => u.id)").then(result => {
        for (var i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
            console.log(result[i]);
        }
    });
```

Also it seems to return an array of arrays so I just gave it the index of the first array which is shard 0 and second is shard 1